# GPU keeps crashing on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, gpu, amd-graphics-card

My PC will sometimes lock up, mostly when playing games but not always, (it happens rarely, but for example also when the computer just booted and I launch Discord or Firefox) then the screen goes black, and then I get visuals back but the colors are extremely distorted or I just see weird patterns.

My GPU is a Sapphire Nitro+ Radeon RX 590 8GD5 Special Edition

I can find some messages using `journalctl` that seem connected to the problem, for example:

```
[drm:amdgpu_dm_commit_planes [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
[drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma1 timeout, signaled seq=20638, emitted seq=20640
[drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
```

The third line sometimes differs (sometimes it lists another process like a game I'm playing or Firefox) but the earliest error always seems to be `Waiting for fences timed out`.

What I've tried based on other reports of instable GPUs similar to mine (though none exactly the same):

- More recent Mesa version using the Oibaf PPA.
- More recent Kernel (5.17.1) using Tuxinvader PPA
- GPU drivers from the AMD website, which seem to pull from their own PPA
- Kernel argument `amdgpu.runpm=0`

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213145